# Is there any way to use repository or a viewmodel object inside a binding adapter function?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-mvvm

I want to load an image using a string that references into room database for the bytearray data
I'm using databinding for this...

Is there any better alternative? Thank You

class BindingUtils(val repository: Repository) {

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("imagebyte")
    fun loadImage(view: ImageView, string: String) {
        CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            val byteArray = repository.databaseGetDataFromString(string)// how to make this line work?
            Glide.with(view)
                .load(byteArray)
                .into(view)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is string ?

Comment: its a path of image url ?

Comment: no string is primary key through which i'm trying to access another column value of bytearray type which contains the actual data in the room database